# Error messages showing in upper right corner of screen when I wanted next to the input

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am studying a system that uses jsf and primefaces. I expected that this snipped showed an error close a the input but the error appears as a message in the upper left corner of screen.

<h:form>

```
    <div class="col-md-4"> 
        <p:outputLabel  value="Rua:"></p:outputLabel>
        <p:inputText id="rua"  value="#{enderecoFace.endereco.rua}"   >
            <p:message for="rua" ></p:message>
            
        <f:validateLength  minimum="3" maximum="3" />

    <h:message  for="rua" style="color:red"></h:message>
        </p:inputText>
        
    </div>
```

What can be going on?

Comment: You have a `p:messages` somewhere on your page probably that is intercepting the validation messages.

Answer (score 1):

First change the position of your `p:message`. It should not be a child of the input component. So do:

```html
<p:outputLabel value="Rua:" />
<p:inputText id="rua" value="#{enderecoFace.endereco.rua}">            
    <f:validateLength minimum="3" maximum="3" />
    <!-- NOT here -->
</p:inputText>
<p:message for="rua" /> <!-- but here instead -->
```

And make sure the message component is **updated** by the component that invokes the action (like a `p:commandButton`).

See also:

- [Understanding PrimeFaces process/update and JSF f:ajax execute/render attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25339056/understanding-primefaces-process-update-and-jsf-fajax-execute-render-attributes)

Messages in the top right (you also mentioned left) corner could be caused by a `p:growl`. Check you template and optionally set the growl properties to your needs.